# How to ask for approval with a custom Workflow in SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-set

I've created a custom document set and a custom Workflow in SPD 2013 to route a document set to multiple approvers. However, I am having an issue with how to initiate/handle the approvers. Is the correct way to go about this by creating a 'approver' task list and assigning the approvers? Or is there a built in way to do this so I do not have to create the approver task list? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the approval process in SPD. You can select/search for the approvers as per steps below -

- Select an approval process in SPD

[image: Select an approval process]

- Click on "these users" and then search for the approvers as per screen below. The approvers will be notified of their tasks via email, which can be opened directly via Outlook tasks, or open in SharePoint

[image]

Comment: This is SPD 2010 action, correct? Will this work with a custom document set?

Comment: Yes it will work with document sets as well.. also with SP2013 and SP2016

Comment: Thank you, I plan to implement this on SharePoint online.

Comment: Also, will this add columns to the document set that show if it was approved or not or will I need to add these manually? Apologies, I have no experience in doing this.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the *Approval workflow* available in SharePoint out-of-box
You can find it under Settings >> Add a workflow

[image: approval workflow]

you can assign approvers on subsequent steps

[image]

Comment: will this allow me to use flow logic depending on the document set form? I need it to send to different individuals depending on the data they enter before creating the document set.